# Slim but long SQL Server 2005 Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, size

I have an SQL table with the following structure:

```
Code1 - int
Code2 - int
Val1  - real
Val2  - real
Val3  - real
```

There is only one index (clustered) were Code1 is the first indexed column and Code2 is the second. The size of a single record is 20bytes.

I need to be able to store around 150,000,000 records and the biggest select operation would be on 500,000 records. I assume that the size of the table will be around 3GB

I would like to know if this design will work or there might be 'unexplained' problems or slowdowns when dealing with such a big table.

Comment: I don't see an id field. Will you be using (code1, code2) as the primary key too? Is (code1, code2) unique?

Comment: what kind of queries will you have on the table? That really determines what needs to be indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very complete question about SQL performance and large tables: [Very large tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677484/very-large-tables-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Basically,  a table with 150 million rows is nothing for SQL Server - won't even break a real sweat :-)

The point really is: how do you access the data? What kind of queries will you have? E.g. if you have queries that have a WHERE clause with just the "col2" column, then you don't have a good setup with a clustered index on (col1,col2).

Also: how is the data distributed in your fields? Which are selective, which are more uniform? If col1 or col2 are highly selective (e.g. a single value selects significantly less than 2% of the data), then use that field for your selects, if ever possible. Indexing something like a "gender" field which might have two, three different values won't really help, since any select using that field as a WHERE clause will always return way too much data to be effective.

Comment: Each query would have a WHERE on both code1 and code2. code1 and code2 are the primary key. I'm looking at ~200,000 records added daily.

There is only one type of query preformed on this table with a range on code1 and a range on code2.

Comment: and how selective are code1 and code2 ?? E.g. given a value for code1, how many percent of the total data gets selected?

Comment: Gilad - the reason marc_s is asking about selectivity on col1 and col2 is because it'll make a difference on which field you should place first.  If col2 is more selective (meaning, there's more unique data in it) then it should be placed first in the clustered index.